# How can I get Doc's notebook from Biff?

Tags: back-to-the-future-the-game

At the estate sale in Back to the Future episode 1: It's about time, I need to get Doc's notebook which contains details and designs for building a time machine back from Biff - it's stored in a model of the Hillsdale town hall which he has taken a liking to.

[image]

None of the conversation options work on him and he's being a jerk about it.

How can I get Doc's notebook from Biff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the guitar away from Biff, follow these steps;

- Use anything in the room, Biff will come and take it off you and your father will step in
- Talk to George (your father) and use the conversation option "I can fight my own battles..." - this will stop him from interfering when Biff takes things from you
- Use the amplifier controls on the huge amp/speaker
- Get your guitar out of the box next to George
- Use your guitar

[image]

Biff will come running along with the courthouse model under his arm, place it on the ground next to the amplifier, and then pinch your guitar off you and play a short riff on it, sending himself flying across the room into a shelving unit, which falls over on top of him;

[image]

Now you can help yourself to Doc's notebook.